# Network between a Ubuntu 12.04 LTS VirtualBox VM and the host OS

Tags: 12.04, virtualbox, macosx, virtualbox-networking

It took me a while to get networking working between my OS X laptop and a Ubuntu 12.04 LTS virtual machine on Virtual Box.  I don't see instructions on here, so I'll post mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open VirtualBox Manager.

Configure the host side of the network as follows:
  VirtualBox, Preferences, Network, Host-only Networks
  +
  Edit
  Adapter
    172.16.0.1
    255.255.255.0
  DHCP Server
    Uncheck 'Enable Server'
  OK, OK

Configure the guest side of the network as follows:
Right click the VM in the left-hand pane.
  Settings, Network, Adapter 2, Enable, Host-only Adapter, vboxnet0, OK

Log into the virtual machine
Open the terminal.
(If you don't have emacs use some other text editor.)
    sudo emacs /etc/network/interfaces

Add this:

```
# The secondary network interface (static IP)  
auto eth1  
iface eth1 inet static  
    address 172.16.0.2  
    netmask 255.255.255.0
```

Save the file, exit, and then do this from the terminal:
    sudo rm /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules
    sudo reboot